# Unable to find webElements using Object spy in UFT

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am trying to find WebElements using Object spy in UFT but it shows only the Win Objects not the Web Element objects such as WebEdit and WebButton. I have selected Web as the Add-in but still its not working. Please can I get a solution to this.[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

UFT's web support works by installing an extension to the browser.

Open Chrome's menu (three horizontal dots -> More tools -> Extensions) and make sure that UFT's extension is installed and enabled.

Comment: 0

I have the same error, but it occurs on MS Edge. I have installed Extension, and it is enabled. I have selected proper add-ons for UFT One. I'm aware of running Edge 1st then UFT One may cause problems, so I run UFT 1st then Edge. Still often this problem occurs. Sometimes even during the work (without resetting neither UFT nor Edge. I'm adding elements etc. Then I try to add next one and Object Spy recognize only: Window: Microsoft Edge WinObject: Chrome Legacy Windows

Comment: Usually resetting UFT Agent extension for Edge and restarting Edge helps, but not always. Sometimes it took me a lot of time resetting everything multiple times (Extension, Edge, UFT One, PC) until it will work again. Do you have any ide what may be the cause of that? It slows my work significantly :(